# I want to perform different actions on tapping different Buttons created dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Buttons are created dynamically and images are given to them through parsed urls, so i viewDidLoad i created them and released them in viewDidLoad only. So, when i click on Buttons i want to perform different tasks on click on different buttons. but i am not able to do it.
I tried to set Tag to them but again it is of no use as it is giving me EXC_BD_ACCESS.... any Help would be appreciated... :)
Code:-

```
@class AppDelegate_iPhone,Litofinter,ParsingViewController;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

    NSMutableArray *array;
    NSString *logoString;
    AppDelegate_iPhone *appDelegate;

    ParsingViewController *obj;

    UIScrollView *scrollView;

    NSMutableArray *idArray;
    NSMutableArray * currentPdfUrl;



}
@property (nonatomic,retain)UIScrollView *scrollView;

//-(void)onTapImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer;
-(void)onTapButton:(id)sender;

@end



#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate_iPhone.h"
#import "Litofinter.h"
#import "ParsingViewController.h"
#import "MyGesture.h"

@implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

-(id)init{
    if(self == [super init]){
        obj = [[ParsingViewController alloc] init];
        array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: obj.LogoMutableArray];
    }
    return self; 
}
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    int x=20,y=10;
    int a=50,b=105;


    appDelegate = (AppDelegate_iPhone *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,500, 460)];   
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,800);
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

    for (Litofinter *lito in appDelegate.logoArray) {

        NSString * urlString = [lito.cLogo stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

        NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
/*              
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [imgView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 90)];
        imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        imgView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
        imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    //  imgView.tag = lito.cId;
    //  NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",imgView.tag);
        NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",lito.cId);


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTapImage:)];
        tgr.delegate = self;
        [imgView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];

        [scrollView addSubview:imgView];

        tgr.view.tag =(int)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lito.cId];
        NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",tgr.view.tag);
    //  NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",lito.cId);

*/      


        UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [imageButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 140, 90)];
        [imageButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imageButton setTag:lito.cId];
        [scrollView addSubview:imageButton];


        UILabel *cName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(a, b, 130, 20)];
        cName.text = lito.cName;
        [scrollView addSubview:cName];

        //Do the rest of your operations here, don't forget to release the UIImageView
        x = x + 150;
        a = a + 140;

        if(x >300)
        {
            y = y +140;
            x = 20;
            b = b +150;
            a = 50;
        }

        //[tgr release];
    //  [imgView release];

    }
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


}

-(void)onTapButton:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",self.view.tag);

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message from mAc" message:@"Tag Id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the selector depending on the button when setting the target

```
[imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onTapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

If you want to do it with tags, it could also work, your bad access is coming from

```
NSLog(@"Tag Id = %@",self.view.tag);
```

Which is assuming that tag is an NSObject (responding to the description selector), when in fact, it is a numeric value. Change it to:

```
NSLog(@"Tag Id = %i",self.view.tag);
```

Also, you want to be careful when using

```
NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

as this is a synchronous API, it's ok if it's local files (although using [UIImage imageNamed:] is more economical as it caches the image data), it's really bad if it's network files (as it blocks the thread until the request ends, which could take ages).

Comment: Thanks jbat100.... but if i write    NSLog(@"Tag Id = %i",self.view.tag); then also my ID is not coming which i have set

Comment: You should get the tag from the sender (which will be the button) NSLog(@"Tag Id = %i",[(UIButton*)sender tag]);

Comment: The ID which i have set and the ID which i am getting are not same as i am setting id which i get from parsed XML and i am getting an id of 8-9 digits.... which i something else...

Comment: How long is your xml id? The max value of NSInteger is NSIntegerMax defined as LONG_MAX (2147483647), is your id large than that?

Comment: My Id is 2,20,21,22 but they are coming like this                                      Tag Id = 79303232  
    Tag Id = 79299904
    Tag Id = 78755760
    Tag Id = 81872640

Comment: Can u please check that wheather i have setted the ID to button correctly as i have setted TAG for button not ID.. :)